# Is there a typo in this paper on Slow feature analysis?

Tags: eigenvalues

In this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHZPS.jpg) you can see the formula (red rectangle added by me for emphasis):
$$
\textbf{V}^\intercal\textbf{HV} = \textbf{D}
$$

Should not this rather be (eigenvalue decomposition):
$$
\textbf{V}^\intercal\textbf{DV} = \textbf{H}
$$

The first two lines of equation 21 would make little sense otherwise.

The full paper can be found here: http://jov.arvojournals.org/article.aspx?articleid=2192836

Comment: I tend to agree with you. From the context of that sentence, it should be as you wrote. Btw, did you get any interesting results with Slow Feature Analysis? I applied it on some time series data but did not get anything conclusive...

Comment: @xeon: I do not have much experience with it in practice yet, so can not comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to be sure we are talking about the same [thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix), the eigendecomposition of a square matrix with $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors is

$$H=VDV^{-1}\qquad\qquad\qquad (1)$$

which for [real symmetric matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Real_symmetric_matrices)

$$H=VDV^T\qquad\qquad\qquad (2)$$

where $D$ is diagonal, and $V$ is the matrix of eigenvectors, such that $V^T=V^{-1}$, so you have $VV^T=I$ and $V^TV=I$. If that's the decomposition we're talking about, then

$$V^THV=V^TVDV^TV=D\,.$$